# Laravel 5.4 how to exclude empty field in url when GET form?

Tags: forms, laravel, url, methods, get

I built form with GET method but when i submit form empty field also pass to url, can i exclude empty field from passing to url ?

For example > when i submit my form url changed to :

```
?jobTitle=Title&jobCompany=CompanyName&jobGovernorate=&jobLocation=&postingDate=ad
```

Here in this example jobGovernorate and jobLocation is empty so i want form skip those when i submit the form.

If there's a way to get url like this

```
?jobTitle=Title&jobCompany=CompanyName&postingDate=ad
```

Because jobGovernorate and jobLocation is empty

Sorry for poor english, Thank you.

Comment: Don't pass the `jobGovernorate` and `jobLocation` if the values are empty on your view. Show your front end code for the detailed explanation. However, it's better to manage these in your controller since I guess in some request, you may be passing values to these parameters.

Comment: Why not use jQuery/JavaScript and add `disabled` attribute to empty fields before form submit

Comment: @ArunCode I already manage all fields in controller if empty but i thought if url changed with only field has value will be better because all fields is in url and url become long with no thing for example if one field has value url will be long for no thing, Thank you for your time.

Comment: @linktoahref Mmmm, i think search form always submit with GET method, i don't know if jQuery will be better or not, and how to do this i'm a beginner so i trying to built my first php laravel script. thank you for your help anyway (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a form as below

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="url_params" name="jobTitle" value="">
    <input type="text" class="url_params" name="jobCompany" value="">
    <input type="text" class="url_params" name="jobGovernorate" value="">
    <input type="text" class="url_params" name="jobLocation" value="">
    <input type="text" class="url_params" name="postingDate" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = '{{ url('/') }}?';
            var total = $(".url_params").length;
            $(".url_params").each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).val().trim().length) {
                       if (index === total - 1) {
                          url += $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val();
                       } else {
                          url += $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val() + "&"; 
                       }                        
                }
            });
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above code will generate an URL based on the field value and redirect to the url. So it won't generate a url with the empty field value key.
And having an empty field value shouldn't make a difference as you could check for the url values in the controller using **`$request->input('key')`**
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

You can use middleware for your problem

```
   class StripEmptyParams
   {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $query = request()->query();
            $querycount = count($query);
            foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
                if ($value == '') {
                    unset($query[$key]);
                }
            }
            if ($querycount > count($query)) {
                $path = url()->current() . (!empty($query) ? '/?' . http_build_query($query) : '');
                return redirect()->to($path);
            }
            return $next($request);
       }
    }
```

then call for specific route like code below

```
Route::get('/search','YourController@search')->middleware(StripEmptyParams::class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Go through array like this, you will just check if your array has empty, will not add the key.

$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
//echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;'); // only for use &amp instead & if needed
```

Answer (score 1):

I have applied the next middleware on a `Laravel 8.x` project to solve a related problem. This may be helpful to other ones...

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StripEmptyParamsFromQueryString
{
    /**
     * Remove parameters with empty value from a query string.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Get the current query and the number of query parameters.

        $query = request()->query();
        $queryCount = count($query);

        // Strip empty query parameters.

        foreach ($query as $param => $value) {
            if (! isset($value) || $value == '') {
                unset($query[$param]);
            }
        }

        // If there were empty query parameters, redirect to a new url with the
        // non empty query parameters. Otherwise keep going with the current
        // request.

        if ($queryCount > count($query)) {
            return redirect()->route($request->route()->getName(), $query);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Note the middleware should only be applied to specific routes, not to all request. In my particular case I have a resource controller and to apply the middleware only to the `index` route I have used the next approach inside the resource controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Middleware\StripEmptyParamsFromQueryString;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(StripEmptyParamsFromQueryString::class)
            ->only('index');
    }
    ...
}
```